# jquery menu error displays block rather than inline on click

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

I've created a dropdown menu using jquery, it displays inline which is how i want it to display and then once clicked to display the other options. However once I click on the link it appears to put the LI tag back into blocks.

Anyone have any ideas as to why its doing this??

HTML

```
<!-- Navigation bar start -->

<div id="navbar">

    <!-- England nav bar start -->
    <li id="engmainnav"><a href="#">England</a>
    <ul id="engsubnav">
        <li class="engli"><? echo $this->Html->link('News', array('controller'=>'Premiership', 'action' =>'news')); ?></li>
        <li class="engli"><? echo $this->Html->link('Results/Fixtures', array('controller'=>'Premiership', 'action' =>'resultsfixtures')); ?></li>
        <li class="engli"><? echo $this->Html->link('Teams', array('controller'=>'Premiership', 'action' =>'teams')); ?></li>
        <li class="engli"><? echo $this->Html->link('Table', array('controller'=>'Premiership', 'action' =>'table'));?></li>

    </ul>
    </li>
    <!-- England nav bar end -->

    <!-- La liga nav bar start-->
    <li id="sanav"><a href="#">Italy</a>
    <ul id="sasubnav">
        <li class="sali"><? echo $this->Html->link('News', array('controller'=>'Italy', 'action' =>'news')); ?></li><br/>
        <li class="sali"><? echo $this->Html->link('Results/Fixtures', array('Italy'=>'Premiership', 'action' =>'resultsfixtures')); ?></li><br/>
        <li class="sali"><? echo $this->Html->link('Teams', array('controller'=>'Italy', 'action' =>'teams')); ?></li><br/>
        <li class="sali"><? echo $this->Html->link('Table', array('controller'=>'Seriea', 'action' =>'table'));?></li><br/>

    </ul>
    </li>



    </div>
    <!-- Navigation bar end -->
```

CSS

```
/* Navigation Style */
#navbar {
background-color: #000666;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#engsubnav {
list-style: none;
margin:none;
display: none;

}

 #sasubnav{
 list-style: none;
margin:none;
display: none;
}

 .engli {
   margin: 0px 0px 0px -38px;
display:block;
 }


 li {
  list-style: none;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
 display:inline;

  }

  ul{
display:inline;
 }
```

Thanks in advance for any help

http://jsfiddle.net/Hm4ns/5/

Comment: Can you set up a JS Fiddle to show the problem?

Comment: Or at the _very_ least, the jquery code and some non-php-wizardry html?

Comment: @utkanos  sorry guys, http://jsfiddle.net/Hm4ns/5/
click on england and then you will se italy drop down to the line below, I want to avoid this. any idea why this is happening??

Comment: @theZ `// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#engmainnav").click(function () {
  if ($("#engsubnav").is(":hidden")) {
      $("#engsubnav").slideDown("slow");
  } else {
      $("#engsubnav").hide();
  }
});
$("#engsubnav").mouseleave(function(){
    $('#engsubnav').hide('slow');
});

$("#sanav").click(function () {
  if ($("#sasubnav").is(":hidden")) {
      $("#sasubnav").slideDown("slow");
  } else {
      $("#sasubnav").hide();
  }
});
$("#sasubnav").mouseleave(function(){
    $('#sasubnav').hide('slow');
});
        
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got `display:block;` in your `.engli` statement (The `LI` elements in the england list all have a class of 'engli'). Your `UL` might be set to inline, but the `LI`s are block, so once they're shown on click, they all drop to new lines.

Comment: ahh ok i see is there any way to get counter this?? i want it to display on the line below in a block

Comment: yes precisely what I'm looking for! what did you do in order to achieve this effect??

Comment: The main change was to move the subnav `UL`s into their own `LI` at the end, so that when it pushed down, there were no main `LI`s after the subnav to get affected. There's also numerous class additions, CSS changes and JS alterations you might want to check out, but the movement of the subnav `UL`s into an `LI` at the end should get you started.